# copying raw mysql data from on server to another

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to clone raw data from all databases on a MySQL instance in Live to a test environment. The network guys have told me the data has been synched and copied across but I can't start the MySQL instance in the test environment. I'm using the innodb engine and I can see the `ibdata1` file, `mysql-bin` files and `ib_logfiles` copied over along with the relevant db folders.

The error I'm getting in the error log looks like the following:

```
130911 13:53:08  InnoDB: Error: table <table-name>
InnoDB: in InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id <id>,
InnoDB: but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have
InnoDB: you deleted or moved .ibd files?
```

The cloning process doesn't stop the Live MySQL instance and I'm wondering is this the problem. I don't want to use `mysqldump` or another backup tool. I just want to copy the raw data across. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: copying the files while they are in use will not make you happy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hot-copy these files and expect them to magically work.

You can use the [innobackupex tool](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html) to create a stable snapshot. This will take care of adjusting the files as necessary to be consistent and complete.